# How to solve this modular equation that has same varible for mod and inside?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For $m>1$
$$
(m-2)^3\cdot(m+2)^4\equiv 4 \mod m
$$
How many possible integers $m$ can be? My modular arithmetic intuition is a bit scarce, so hints and explanations are more appreciated.

Comment: Well, $m \equiv 0 \pmod m$. So your equation says $(-2)^3 \cdot 2^4 \equiv 4 \pmod m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments by [Fredrik Meyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/4284):

$${(m - 2)^3}\cdot{(m + 2)^4} \equiv {(0-2)^3}\cdot{(0+2)^4} \equiv 4 \pmod m,$$

so that $m \mid (-128 - 4) = -132$.  In other words, if you restrict $m > 1$, then $m \mid 132 = {2^2}\cdot{3}\cdot{11}$.  Thus, there are $d(m) - 1 = (2+1)\cdot(1+1)\cdot(1+1) - 1 = 3\cdot{2}\cdot{2} - 1= 12 - 1 = 11$ possible choices for $m$ (because of the restriction $m > 1$).

Comment: I get that you've calculated how many integers that divides $132$, little question: What $d$ stands for at function?

Comment: $d(m)=\sigma_{0}(m)$, which is just the number-of-divisors function (see OEIS sequence [A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005) for some references).

Comment: So if
$$m = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
is the **prime factorization** of $m$, then
$$d(m) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{\bigg(\alpha_i + 1\bigg)}.$$

Comment: I knew the strategy but notations are new to me :D Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, @AbdullahUYU!   =)